# Disabling TLS 1.0 breaks ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

Running on Windows Server 2012R2

I am trying to disable TLS 1.0 on IIS because client has a site scanner which highlights that as a security problem.

I have a clean test server set up and App is running fine until I disable TLS 1.0.

I updated all the appropriate settings:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

In the event viewer, I get:

> A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may
>   result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined
>   fatal error code is 70. The Windows SChannel error state is 105.

If I revert the registry settings just for TLS 1.0 (Enabled, not DisabledByDefault), everything is fine again.

Using in system.web:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Since you have disabled TLS 1.0, code needs to be updated to communicate over TLS 1.2

Following line of code can be added before making a request to service hosted on your server

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: @MohsinMehmood this is a regular web app.  Site is being access through IE.  When site is running with TLS 1.0 enabled, it still shows that IE has connected over TLS 1.2.

Comment: Use IISCrypto tool to ensure that TLS 1.2 is enabled. This tool will provide a nice GUI for enabling multiple versions of TLS. Also, test your website using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Yes.  That is how I generated the registry change file for my client and for scripting the setup changes and reversions.  I also used the Qualys scanner to verify why they are seeing the site reported for TLS 1.0 vulnerability through scans even though all browsers are negotiating their connections at TLS 1.2.  However, neither of those things resolve the issue with IIS.

Comment: Check which .NET Framework version is installed. Only a later version reads system default for TLS setup. If you want to stick to an old release, the source code must be changed to switch to TLS 1.2 default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/

Comment: @LexLi 4.7.1 is installed, I am going to look at putting on 4.7.2 right now.

Comment: Do read the article on TLS sections to learn the changes.

Comment: @LexLi 4.7.2 framework installed, problem still there.

Comment: I would try to get ASP.Net out of the loop by testing a simple website with a static file. This is could easily be an IIS problem.

Comment: Try to disable TLS 1.0 only for the server. After all that is what the scanner detected. I guess that even if the client 1.0 is enabled, it will still attempt an 1.2 connection.

Comment: What version of IIS is it? Are you using SQL?

Comment: @HackSlash IIS 8, it does connect to a SQL Server.

Comment: @MartinLiversage I made a simple test.html page in the same folder, and it loads fine - properties shows it is loaded over https.

Comment: @edixon It appears that potentially the SQL Server connection is the issue.  I re-enabled 1.0 client and have better results.  Now to test same change in clientproduction environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your site could be communicating with something over SSL that doesn't support TLS 1.1+. You could allow outgoing TLS 1.0 connections which the site scanner wouldn't see, but these connections would be less secure.

Comment: From the detailed logging, I only see successful connections at TLS 1.2, and there are no further details that this failure comes from trying to communicate externally (which the site does not do).

Comment: Ultimately, I think this was the cause - the internal outbound SQL Server connection was being forced to TLS 1.2 and the SQL Server didn't support that.

Answer (score 9):

The application itself must be updated to support TLS 1.2 handshakes, so it's not something you can necessarily change if you only have access to configuration.  If the underlying code does not support it, it will not work.

If the code targets .NET 4.6, I believe, TLS 1.2 will work natively.  In 4.5, a line of code must be put in place such that it is executed before any networking occurs.  The code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Comment: This has no effect because the schannel issue happens before code is run in for example the global.asax.

Comment: Everything up the whole stack needs to support TLS 1.2. The OS, IIS, SQL, and the application.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .net 4.7 or higher try this.

I have used [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) for this. You disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1, apply and restart. After this all your applications, SharePoints and sites will use TLS 1.2

You should also indicate the destination version in your web.config file

> ```
> <system.web>
>    <httpRuntime targetFramework = "4.7.2" />
>    <compilation targetFramework = "4.7.2"> </compilation>
> </system.web>
> ```

This will make it support TLS 1.2 and also always force this protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to enable schannel logging to get more info?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/260729/how-to-enable-schannel-event-logging-in-iis

Hope that will reveal the missing piece.

Comment: I set logging to 7, and there are a number of successful information-level messages around the error message posted above:

An SSL client handshake completed successfully. The negotiated cryptographic parameters are as follows.

   Protocol: TLS 1.2
   CipherSuite: 0xC028
   Exchange strength: 256

Comment: Also: An SSL server handshake completed successfully. The negotiated cryptographic parameters are as follows.

   Protocol: TLS 1.2
   CipherSuite: 0xC028
   Exchange strength: 256